# Dubs Connman wifi connect Qt

Tags: qt, wifi, dbus, connman

I'am working on an imx6, and i'am trying to connect to a wifi network through Dbus with a Qt application.
The application connect correctly to connman via Dbus and i recieve correctly the wifi services.
The problem is that when i try to connect to a wiif network i catch this error :

**"Method "Connect" with signature "ss" on interface "net.connman.Service" doesn't exist**

The code that i'am using in Qt application to coonect to a wifi network is:

```
QDBusInterface *iface =
new QDBusInterface("net.connman","/net/connman/technology/wifi","net.connman.Service",QDBusConnection::systemBus());

if (!iface->isValid())
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Fail to connect to the Connman Technology interface: " << QDBusConnection::systemBus().lastError().message();
}



QDBusReply<void> reply = iface->call("Connect","/net/connman/service/wifi_88da1a4db14c_41684179_managed_psk","password");

if (!reply.isValid())
{
    qDebug() << "Call connect result: " << reply.error().message();
}
```

When i try to connect to the wifi network with shell commands using connmanctl it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on imx6. The solution which works for me is creating a configuration file for network before invoking *Connect* method.

The file should be in /var/lib/connman and name *[SSID].config* .
File content:

```
[service_wifi_PUT_SERVICE_NAME]
Name = PUT_SSID
Type = wifi
Passphrase = PUT_PASSWORD
```

And try connecting in this way:

```
QDBusInterface *iface =  new QDBusInterface("net.connman", QString{"/net/connman/service/%1"}.arg(SERVICE_NAME), "net.connman.Service", QDBusConnection::systemBus());
QDBusReply<void> reply = iface->call("Connect");
if(!reply.isValid() {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The Qt app I'm working on at the moment requires an interface to connman, and I found this library to be helpful [libconnman-qt](https://github.com/sailfishos/libconnman-qt/tree/master).

Understanding how the agent works was also bit tricky, but looking at the connman api documents directly was also helpful [connman documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/connman/connman.git/tree/doc?id=HEAD).  It helped to start with the "overview-api.txt".